# Why can Renamon disappear, while Guilmon and Terriermon can't?

Tags: digimon-tamers

In *Digimon Tamers*, we see Renamon disappear or fade out after she is no longer needed several times. (For instance, she disappears at the end of episode 7, after Rika, Henry, and Takato have rescued Guilmon.) Meanwhile, Guilmon and Terriermon do not seem capable of this: Takato has to take pains to hide Guilmon (ep. 2), and Henry has to pass off Terriermon as a stuffed animal when he is at home (ep. 1).

Why is this the case? Does it have something to do with the monsters themselves, or is it an issue of the abilities of the Tamer? (But Henry seems knowledgable enough to me, so I am not entirely convinced by that theory.)

Comment: Maybe Renamon is only one of the three that knows how? [Ep7](http://digimon-tamers.wikia.com/wiki/Now_You_See_It,_Now_You_Don%27t) - *After she leaves, Takato asks Rika if Digimon can disappear for no reason. Rika says probably, since Digimon are just data*

Comment: Right, but in that episode, what Takato is concerned with is the _irrevocable_ disappearance of Digimon, and that seems different from what Renamon is doing. (She nearly disappears in the same way in that episode, where part of her body looks lighter, and that's different from her "normal" disappearance, where it just looks like she disperses or fades out all at once.)

Comment: It’s been years since I’ve watched tamers, so must’ve misinterpreted the context of the scene based on the wiki text

Comment: I think, that it is just one of Renamon's skills, but haven't found proof, yet.

Answer (score 2):

Renamon is based on / heavily influenced by the Japanese kitsune, which have mystical abilities, most famously that of illusions. On top of that, Renamon has ninja-like speed, and I'd say it's a combination of both that it's using here.

Blink an eye and you'll miss it. One moment it's there, the next it's gone and only leaves a fading stand-in illusion of itself (what a trickster), as it's probably hiding away in the shadows or trees. Or it's actually using illusion abilities to straight up become invisible for extended periods of time (that would have to be harder to keep up, but who knows).

Point being, these abilities would have to be balanced for fights - can't just have Renamon "godmode" and stay completely invisible, after all. That's why I'm assuming it has to stand completely still and concentrate to actually become and stay invisible, and therefore, using it's speed to jump away and leaving behind a stand-in illusion from it's physical hiding place would be less taxing and preferable, whenever possible.

A kitsune's mystical powers increase with age and amount of tails they have - from one, up to nine tails (see Kyubimon, Renamon's Champion level). Ninetales from *Pokémon*, nine-tails Kurama (Kyuubi) from *Naruto*... kitsune are a big, big thing in Japanese mythology.

Answer (score -2):

Renamon fades out because she moves fast than the eye can see. See renamon vs deathbattle to see how fast she is.don't know how rika and renamon were talking in that one episode where everyone looked around them stopped moving.

Comment: Sources? Include them in your answer.